# How to get the data object from a certain template instance in Chrome Console in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

```
<template name="orderForm">

  {{> photographyServicesForm}}
  {{> videographyServicesForm}}
  {{> onlineProductsForm}}

</template>
```

If I go to the `orderForm` page is there a way to get the `data` inside of the `orderForm` Blaze template instance when I'm in Chrome Console? I know how to get it inside the `orderForm` callbacks, events, helpers, and inside the HTML, but I want to be able to easily check up on it and even update it from the Chrome Console.

I also know that there are four different template instances when I go to this `orderForm`. Obviously `Template.orderForm` doesn't work because it's not the current template instance.

**EDIT**

Here's the answer:

```
<template name="orderForm">

  <div id="orderForm">
    {{> photographyServicesForm}}
    {{> videographyServicesForm}}
    {{> onlineProductsForm}}
  </div>

</template>
```

`Blaze.getData($('#orderForm')[0])`

It should be noted that the same data available on the `orderForm` template is also available to its child templates - `photographyServicesForm`, `videographyServicesForm`, `onlineProductsForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check out [Blaze.getData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata) and [Blaze.getView](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getview).

With `Blaze.getData` you can simply do this:

```
Blaze.getData(document.querySelector('.someelement'))
```

This works pretty well, but you have to have an element inside the template-instance you can query for.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Feels a bit goofy but it works. I can do `Blaze.getData($('#order-summary')[0])` and it brings back the data. What I would have to do in my example above would be to set an ID or otherwise easily-selectable element in my `orderForm` html. I'm updating my OP.

Comment: Just so it has been said; I wouldn't use an id for that. I only use them for anchors. Using an id makes it far less modular.

Comment: Right. For my purposes though I need it to be that direct. And I think that in general for Meteor Template instances, you need to be exact if you want to bring back the data stored for that particular Template.